# Read color bil file striped in QGIS, R or gdal

Tags: qgis, gdal, r, band-interleaved-by-line

I am trying to render a bil file I downloaded from [this link](http://internet.contenidos.inegi.org.mx/contenidos/Productos/prod_serv/contenidos/espanol/bvinegi/productos/geografia/ortofoto_1_10/889463187356_b.zip), but in QGIS, R raster::raster() or gdal_translate it shows rotated and with stripes, as shown on the picture; I think it is a problem with the hdr file, I remember opening them in arcmap and they would show without trouble.
[image: b]

Comment: Is it an RGB raster? It could be that nbands option isn't being recognized or is missing, here's a link that explains a lot about BIL/BSQ files and their headers https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/bil-bip-and-bsq-raster-files.htm#:~:text=The%20BIL%2C%20BIP%2C%20and%20BSQ,map%2C%20and%20latitude%20and%20longitude. Are you trying to load the raster using the bil file or the hdr file? I haven't used band interleaved in a while but I remember to get them to display in QGIS properly the .hdr file was selected as the layer to load.

Comment: I tried loading the hdr but it's not working either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix for these images was a two part solution, one for the stripes and a further one for the CRS:

First: hiding .aux file from the search path, which had redundant information to the header (.hdr), as mentioned by @Michael Stimson, this can be done by renaming the file extension or by removing the file. This fixes the stripes on the picture.

Second: QGIS doesn't recognize the .prj format that accompanies these file, which looks like this:

```
Projection  Universal Transverse Mercator
Datum       ITRF92
Zone        14
Units       METERS
Spheroid    GRS 80
```

so I copied a WKT from a shapefile .prj contents and replaced the file's,
it must look like this:

```
PROJCS["WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_14N",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-99.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

Resulting image is:
[image]

Comment: Was the origin and cell size specified in the header? If so it makes the updated aux file redundant which is a dangerous situation like a world file and GeoTIFF, some software reads the .TFW file others read the GeoTIFF tags which is fine if they agree but if the image is modified only the one set of coordinates gets updated resulting in different placement in other software systems.. if that's all you have in your AUX file I suggest to rename the .AUX to .RedundantAUX just in case you need to refer to it at some stage removing the association entirely and use the .HDR information exclusively.

Comment: Thank you, it also works removing the aux file from the directory; what I couldn't accomplish was to set the crs on the file (with the un-modified aux file it would place it where it should), I found no documentation on the aux file, to set the thing to work properly

Comment: For a BIL a prj file should be good enough to establish CRS, if you've got a shapefile in the correct CRS copy the .prj and change the name to exactly match the BIL and HDR, I know it's a bit of a hack but it is simple and usually effective; this method also works for ASCII files (.asc).

Comment: these files came with a prj file; but it was not like a shp's prj, but rather a two column file; I did as you suggested and it worked; in the end I hid the aux file by changing the extension and re-wrote the prj as a shapefiles, may you post an answer so i can mark it as accepted?

Comment: I would prefer that you answer your own question, with screen shots and text file contents, you have the data that has been fixed. I'll check back in a few hours and upvote your answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the guidance!